# Keep screen from locking ionic/cordova

Tags: ionic2, lockscreen

So y’all know how when google maps is running and when you press the lock screen on your phone to turn the screen off and press it again to turn it back on, the lock screen doesn’t show up and it opens directly in the application.

Any ideas of how to do this with Ionic/Cordova? Or does anyone know how google does it?

Comment: Its a default behavior. if you lock screen and unlock it your application will be displayed.

Comment: Perhaps I worded this wrong. I want to lock the screen, and upon pressing the power button, rather than initially showing the lock screen (which I have to unlock) I want it to immediately open into the application.

Comment: if you have security code (pattern, passwords, face unlock, etc etc) then you cant. but if you have only swipe to unlock screen then it will open your application immediately.

Comment: Google​ ​maps does it. I'll not sure you're following what I'm asking. Thank you though